# Como alinear botones en diferentes divs

Tags: css3

Buenas tengo un pequeño problema quiero alinear los botones de "Ver Articulo"

El problema viene cuando el titulo de la nota es extenso y cubre 2 o 3 lineas.

Cuando en una fila hay puro articulo de 2 lineas queda bien pero si hay uno de 2 lineas y dos de 3 lineas queda disparejo el boton.

Como puedo hacer que el botón siempre se quede fijo hasta abajo.

Este es el script que utilizo para dar formato a las entradas

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[image: Y este es el problema con el botón]

```html
<!-- Este div hace que los articulos se dividan en 3 -->
          <div class='uk-width-large-1-3 uk-width-medium-1-1' style= 'padding-bottom: 25px;'>
           <!--Agarra la imagen del URL y la pone de contenido-->
              <a class='cs-hover-effect' href='#'>
                  <img class='uk-width-medium-1-1' src=''/></a>
              <div class='cs-article-summary'>
               <!-- Agarra el titulo del URL y lo despliega-->
                  <a class='cs-hover-effect' href='#'>
                      <h4 class='cs-article-summary-title cs-font-roboto cs-color-text-2 uk-text-bold'></h4>
                  </a>
                   <!-- Muestra las primeras 15 palabras del articulo -->
                  <a class='cs-hover-effect' href='#'>
                      <h5 class='cs-font-roboto cs-color-text-3'></h5>
                  </a>
                   <!-- Boton para ir a ver articulo -->
                  <a class='uk-button cs-color-background-2 cs-color-text cs-font-roboto cs-button2 cs-hover-effect' href='#'>Ver Artículo</a>
              </div>
          </div>
```

```css
.cs-button2 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 2px 20px;
        font-size: 13px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        float: left;
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega un ejemplo en el que podamos ver el error que estás teniendo. Actualmente es imposible que te podamos ayudar al 100% ya que no podemos adivinar como tienes el HTML y CSS en tu proyecto.

Comment: No entiendo, puedes agregar una imagen de lo que quieres hacer o un fragmento del código que estás usando?

Comment: Agregue el script que estoy utilizando y la imagen de los botones, que están disparejos.
Quisiera que sin importar el contenido estuvieran al mismo margen

Comment: @JesusSnd_ Sería mucho mejor si pudieras agregar el código de la imagen como texto. De hecho, si presionas Cntrl+M sobre tu pregunta podrás agregar el código bien formateado en la misma, para una mejor comprensión y para que podamos copiar/editar de una manera mucho más fácil. Gracias :)

Comment: Gracias Francisco Romero ya adjunte como me dijiste el código del script y el css del botón

Comment: podrias editar tu pregunta y agregar de javascript ? y todo el css de la pagina? .,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No logro ver bien lo que estas haciendo pero creo que es algo parecido a esto;

https://codepen.io/parredondov/pen/vRBxBN

En fin, es una vista de los articulos. al contenedor padre, en tu caso, `.uk-width-large-1-3` le pones una altura minima, asi todos los contenedores tendran la misma altura sin importar el largo del titulo. (esto lo puedes lograr con javascript en caso de que no haya una altura fija)

```
.uk-width-large-1-3{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.cs-button2 {
 /* tu css */
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió a la perfección.